# hendecagonsssss

Tags: asymptote

I need help with my homework.
Does anyone know how to draw a hendecagon(eleven sided shape) on LaTeX or asymptote? Because I have tried many times to find an answer but I can't. 
So can somebody please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43420/15925, replacing `6` by `11` in the assignment to `regular polygon sides`

Comment: I need asymptote, not TikZ because the website doesn't accept TikZ only latex or asymptote

Comment: TikZ is just a LaTeX package...

Comment: Anyway in any drawing program all you want is straightl ines between points evenly distributed on a circle - those are easy to write down in polar coordinates.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152191/15925 which also includes an asymptote version

Comment: @Andrew Swan I found out how to draw one and how do you get the grey highlight around the words?

Comment: [asy]
size(9cm);
pair cis(real magni, real argu) { return (magni*cos(argu*pi/180),magni*sin(argu*pi/180)); }

for(int b=1; b<2; b+=1){
for(int a=6; a<7; a+=1){
int n=a+5*b;
pair ctr=(2.5*a,-2.5*b);
real r=1; pair offs=(0,0);
if(n==3) {r=2/3; offs=(0,-1/3);}
for(int i=1; i<2*n; i+=2){
draw(ctr+cis(r/cos(pi/n),270+(i-2)*180/n)+offs---ctr+cis(r/cos(pi/n),270+i*180/n)+offs,blue);
};
};
};
[/asy]

Comment: Please update your question, to say explain what you have tried and what you are missing.